# アップは? バッチリです。How to understand this exchange?

Tags: translation, anime, japanese-to-english

> アップは? バッチリです。

The above sentence is taken straight from Haikyuu!! S01E07.

The subs translate to:

> アップは? > Did you get warmed up?
>
> バッチリです。> Perfectly.

The context is a coach asks his player if he's warmed up so he can swap him into the ongoing match, to which the player responds that he did.

I am having trouble understanding アップは? Can someone break it down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume that アップ is a transliteration of the English word 'up'; an abbreviation of 'warmed up', 'fired up' etc.

The は is just the usual topic marker. This is a simple way of making a question, like お名前は to ask what someone's name is.